# What is the functionality of the pull down resistor in mosfet circuits?

Tags: capacitor, mosfet, resistors, circuit-design, pulldown

I would be appreciative if the functionality of the pull-down resistor connected to the output of a mosfet circuit could be explained thoroughly.

Is it mandatory to have the resistor and also the capacitor in the output?

And is it better to put a mosfet with its gate connected to the source, instead of the aforementioned resistor?

[image: Here is a sample circuit]

Comment: What is that circuit supposed to do? It has models.spi at the top which suggest this is modeling an SPI channel.

Comment: the picture is about tri state buffers. However, it is just a sample. I want to know the functionality of such resisitors in any mosfet-based circuits

Comment: There are no MOSFET's in the circuit. That makes it hard to answer your question. Rload is not a pulldown. It is meant to model the load on the outputs of the buffers. Cload is probably also meant to model the capacitive load on the output of the buffers. I am going to vote to close this question as it seems like you don't really know what you are asking. However, if you edit it so that it makes sense I will remove my vote.

Comment: everything here is built using mosfets, however, I have put the block diagrams of them because it would become a very big circuit to show here.
Here is the link:
https://www.silvaco.com/examples/harmony/section1/example6/index.html

Comment: Perhaps they are technically MOSFET's. But generally, the term "MOSFET" is used to describe discrete transistors. Logic gates and buffers would be called "CMOS." (Complimentary Metal Oxide Semiconductor). They call it complimentary meaning that both PMOS and NMOS are present on the same die. The CMOS process was a pretty important breakthrough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is a simulation of tri-state buffers. A buffer normally drives/sends a signal to some destination.

The Rload and Cload are there just to simulate as if the buffer is connect to an other input.

Just to emphasize: you normally do NOT put such a load on the output of a driver. It is only here to make the simulation more realistic.

Comment: Thanks. I have to ask that when I simulate a tri state inverter in hspice, the output is not stable when the enable of tri state is off. Does such a pull down circuit help to have better output voltage in this situation? Or Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: "when enable of tri state is off." Is ambiguous. It is better to use: *the output is tri-stated* or to use *the output is driven.* Note that in the diagram above you should never drive BOTH outputs at the same time.

Comment: Yes, better to say the output is tri stated. In this case, the output is floating in the range: [0-60m]. How can I fix this to have a stable zero output? Is the pull down resistor helpful? Or connect another transistor which is connected to the ground?

Comment: A tri-stated output is supposed to be floating and yes the pull-down helps as it  makes that the output goes low instead of swerving all over the place.